# Parse.Promise can't catch an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform

I'm working on a project which use Parse.com npm package in NodeJS, and here is a problem:

```js
  Parse.Promise.as(true).then(function() {
    throw new Error('here is an error');
  }).then(function(done) {
    console.log('done', done);
  }, function(err) {
    console.log('err', err);
  });
```

This code should logs "err" and "here is an error".
But it's not. Just thrown the error immediately like this:

```js
Error: here is an error
    at module.exports.app.get.res.title.js.css.route.noChat (/Users/Nemo/dev/workspace/snapfitWeb/lib/event.js:10:11)
    at wrappedResolvedCallback (/Users/Nemo/dev/workspace/snapfitWeb/node_modules/parse/build/parse-latest.js:4082:40)
    at /Users/Nemo/dev/workspace/snapfitWeb/node_modules/parse/build/parse-latest.js:4144:35
    at runLater (/Users/Nemo/dev/workspace/snapfitWeb/node_modules/parse/build/parse-latest.js:4127:14)
    at _.extend.then (/Users/Nemo/dev/workspace/snapfitWeb/node_modules/parse/build/parse-latest.js:4143:9)
    at module.exports.app.get.res.title.js.css.route.noChat (/Users/Nemo/dev/workspace/snapfitWeb/lib/event.js:9:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Nemo/dev/workspace/snapfitWeb/lib/event.js:17:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
```

Environment: 
Node v0.10.38 
express@4.12.3
parse@1.4.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convey an error to the error callback, return a rejected promise, like this:

```
Parse.Promise.as(true).then(function() {
    return Parse.Promise.error("here is an error");
}).then(function(done) {
    console.log('done', done);
}, function(err) {
    console.log('err', err);
});
```

Comment: You are right. BTW where is the document about Parse's Promise? Can't find it now.

Comment: Glad to help.  I looked for the same doc in order to answer.  It seems the "guide" about promises has gone missing, but the api ref doc is still here: https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Promise.html